# Mongodb query to get document count for each month of a specific year

Tags: mongodb

I have a time field as below in my collection.

`"time" : NumberLong(1531958400000)`

I first want to query documents by the current year(using $match) and then get the document count for each month.
I have managed to match the year using the below query.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
   {$project: {
        year: { "$year":{"$add":[new Date(0),"$time"]}}
     }
   },
   {$match: {year: 2021}}
])
```

How can I write a mongodb query for the mentioned scenario?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following:

1. parsed the timestamp using `$date`
2. compare the parsed date field with current year
3. `$group` by `$month` value to get the count

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0WzJNHjcwvf) for your reference.